# Intentionally create Merge Conflict

Tags: merge-conflict-resolution

I have pulled the files from GitHub already. Now I need to create a merge-conflict.

How do I intentionally create a merge conflict on GitHub?

Comment: Edit the same line in two branches, and try to merge.

Answer (score 7):

## Edit the same line in two branches, and try to merge

> Merge conflicts in git happen, when two branches were changed on the same line or in the same content of a file before a merge. If you just extend a file or append something, git usually just figures it out by itself.

Use this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir git-repo
cd git-repo
git init
touch my_code.sh
git add my_code.sh
echo "echo Hello" > my_code.sh
git commit -am 'initial'
git checkout -b new_branch
echo "echo \"Hello World\"" > my_code.sh
git commit -am 'first commit on new_branch'
git checkout master
echo "echo \"Hello World!\"" > my_code.sh
git commit -am 'second commit on master'
git merge new_branch
```

script is from: https://jonathanmh.com/how-to-create-a-git-merge-conflict/

title credits: `Alexander O'Mara`